# Run multiple python functions using flask

Tags: python, serial-port, arduino, flask

**2nd UPDATE**

Almost there!! But getting a "ValueError: Attempting to use a port that is not open"

> ```
> File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1701, in __call__
> return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
>
> File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1689, in wsgi_app
> response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
>
> File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1687, in wsgi_app
> response = self.full_dispatch_request()
>
> File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1360, in full_dispatch_request
> rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
>
> File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1358, in full_dispatch_request
> rv = self.dispatch_request()
>
> File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1344, in dispatch_request
> return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
>
> File "G:\OverAir\arduino\server.py", line 19, in light_off
> board.output([pin])
>
> File "G:\OverAir\arduino\arduino.py", line 16, in output
> self.__sendData(len(pinArray))
>
> File "G:\OverAir\arduino\arduino.py", line 56, in __sendData
> while(self.__getData()[0] != "w"):
>
> File "G:\OverAir\arduino\arduino.py", line 61, in __getData
> return self.serial.readline().rstrip('\n')
>
> File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 221, in read
> if not self.hComPort: raise portNotOpenError
>
> ValueError: Attempting to use a port that is not open
> ```
>
> UPDATE
>
> The code from @Blender answer below is probably correct. The issue now
>   I am having is I'm getting  **"SerialException: could not open port
>   COM5: [Error 5] Access is denied."**
>
> However, if I run my original, on.py or off.py script individually, it
>   works fine...I don't see how the new code is not working...unless does
>   it try to open COM5 twice??
>
> END UPDATE

I trying to run multiple python functions, or separate .py scripts, using Flask; in order to generate separate URLs. Just trying to turn the Arduino ON/OFF running it locally.

For example, I have on.py and off.py and want to build sever.py. 
So, when I open 127.0.0.1:5000/on it runs on.py, similarly 127.0.0.1:5000/off runs off.py,

After a few hours, I just decided to add both .py functions into the server.py, but of course it doesn't work...I think I just don't understand the parameters usage.

Really thank you in advance!

```
## Open a serial connection with Arduino.

from time import sleep
from arduino import Arduino

from flask import Flask


b = Arduino("COM5",9600)
pin = 13
num = 5

ON = Flask("Light_ON")
OFF = Flask("Light_OFF")


def LightON():
    #declare output pins as a list/tuple
    b.output([pin])
    b.setHigh(pin)
    b.close()
    return 'Light is ON'

def LightOFF():
    #declare output pins as a list/tuple
    b.output([pin])
    b.setLow(pin)
    return 'Light is OFF'

@ON.route('/ON')
@OFF.route('/OFF')

ON.run()
OFF.run()  //I know this doesn't run, just not sure how to include it.
```

Comment: Why are you using two flask instances? Why don't you just do this all from one app?

Comment: could I trouble you to tell me how to go about it please? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
from arduino import Arduino
from flask import Flask

app = Flask('light_control')
board = Arduino('COM5', 9600)
pin = 13

@app.route('/on')
def light_on():
    board.output([pin])
    board.setHigh(pin)
    board.close()

    return 'Light is ON'

@app.route('/off')
def light_off():
    board.output([pin])
    board.setLow(pin)
    # board.close() ???

    return 'Light is OFF'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand what you mean. But, now I'm getting *Restarting with reloader, can't open port COM5: access denied. But, if I run these on.py off.py individually, it works...

Comment: Do you have more than one instance running?

Comment: @OverAir - you'll want to add `use_reloader=False` to the `app.run` call - otherwise, in debug mode flask will start, then load a subprocess to serve the requests (so it can reload as you make changes.)  Alternately, you can connect to the board *in* your web requests (i. e. `light_on(): board = Arduino(...)` etc.).

Comment: @SeanVieira Thank you so much Sean, that last part of connecting in web requests...can you please expand on that, or reference a link? Thanks again!

Comment: @SeanVieira Almost there! I'm getting a "ValueError: Attempting to use a port that is not open" But, no longer that reloader issue!!

Comment: @OverAir: Port `5000` is already in use. Try killing the process that uses that port first. If you can't, use a different port: `app.run(port=5001)`

Comment: @Blender thank you, but it's still doing the same thing, works for /on but get the ValueError for /off

Comment: @Blender I added it above under **2nd Update** thank you so much for your time!

Comment: I finally got the project to work, but decided to install IIS on windows 8 and enabling CGI. I'm sorry, I didn't know that could be done ! Thank you everyone for your help, I learned a great deal =)